# Read emails from Exchange server

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exchange-server

How can i read all inbound and outbound email from our exchange server using .vet (VB/C#)?

Basically we have a Quote management system and we send Quote out via email. What we really want to achieve is Read all outgoing and incoming emails and copy the email to specific Quote folder in server.

I want to server get emails which have a specific Subject line something like "Quote #12345".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a few approaches

1. Use a Transport Rule to copy any email that matches your particular subject to a particular Mailbox and then just process any email in that Mailbox using EWS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535506(v=exchg.150).aspx
2. Create a Transport Agent which will allow you to process all messages that pass through the Transport Pipeline https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125012(v=exchg.150).aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thank you very much Glen. I will try to implement solution 1. Will let you know how i go.

Thanks again.