# Read emails from Exchange server best soulation

Tags: .net, exchange-server, background-process

I am trying to access the Exchange server 2013 and read email,

I can read it with C# console application which mentioned in this ticket, for monitoring I can run this console application as a task in windows task manager or put it as a service which is running in windows server services.

[Read emails from Exchange server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271692/read-emails-from-exchange-server)

I have another option for running my code for reading from Exchange Server.

I can write my code and put in IIS and set a refresh time, call that page every specific time within this approach I'll have good control of the page, for instance, application error and all IIs functionally which help to monitor

I think maybe there is a better approach for this task which is more reliable.

Kindly tell me which approach do you think is better, what other solution  do you think is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create a transport agent solution. 
Keywords: onSubmit, onCategorize.